# I'm trying to write a method that reads a text file and, for each line, prints out the number of words in the line

Tags: java, filereader

I think the title is self explanatory. I'm trying to print how many words are in each line of a text file, the following is what I have so far:

```
package filereader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordNumberer
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File file = new File("story.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int wordCount = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
          wordCount += 1;
          System.out.println(wordCount);
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? We help you correct problems, not produce code for you.

Comment: You should debug your code first. Have you?

Comment: My problem is that I'm getting an infinite loop. My code continually prints larger and larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should print the result outside of second while loop and you need to reset count before you start counting for next line.

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){               
       while (scanner.hasNext()){
           wordCount += 1;
       }
       System.out.println(wordCount);
       wordCount = 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (scanner.hasNext())` is an infinite loop if you don't consume the next token, you have the same problem with `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` if you don't consume the line .

Other than that, as other people already pointed pout, you should print the count only at the end of the line, then reset the counter to 0.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
          wordCount += 1;
          scanner.next();// consume token

        }

        System.out.println(wordCount);// print count for the current line
        wordCount  = 0; // reset counter
        scanner.nextLine();//consume line
    }
```